# runtime error: automation error while trying to connect to oracle database via Excel macro

Tags: excel, oracle10g, database-connection, excel-2007, vba

I am a beginner to excel 2007. I am trying to make a connection to the oracle database 10G and extract data from it. I am getting  **"Runtime error :'-2147467259(80004005)':
Automation error unspecified error"** . This code is working for my senior.Please Help!!

```
 Sub build_database_connection()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn= New ADODB.Connection
servername = example.com
UserName = example
pass = example

cn_cdcp.Open "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=" & servername & ";User ID=" & UserName & "Password=" & pass & ";"

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is cn_cdcp declared?

Comment: A few questions; Should `cn_cdcp` be `cn`? And `example.com` be `"example.com"`?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance there are a few issues with you code above and I'm not sure if its just a copying of the problem but here I go anyway.

```
Sub build_database_connection()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    servername = "example.com" '<~~ the ".." defines a string
    UserName = "example" '<~~ the ".." defines a string
    pass = "example" '<~~ the ".." defines a string

    'cn_cdcp doesn't exist use cn instead
    'correct connection string should be 
    '"Provider=msdaora;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
    '<~~ you missed a ;
    cn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=" & servername & _
        ";User ID=" & UserName & ";Password=" & pass & ";"

End Sub
```

In saying the above I think your issue is in the connection string. See [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle-msdaora) for more.

Yours should be `Provider=msdaora;Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`